# storing user input rating for each given phrase and print in the order of rating given

Tags: java, sorting, java.util.scanner

I basically have these 5 random sentences that are stored in the array and I basically want the user to input a score for each sentence out of 10 and store that in the array and then include a way of sorting the sentences in order of the scores given to them and print them in that order 
i.e. from highest to lowest.

I am new to java, would really appreciate if someone could help out on how do I go about solving this problem, apparently I have to use comparatives, but how do I use that? Is there any other way?

```
    public static void loopswithinloops()   

    {

    String[] sentences = {"I am blessed to have you in my life. You are the one thing in my life that is true and real",
                    "I am honoured to have you by my side to love and to cherish each day of our lives.", 
                    "More precious than any other thing in my life is to see your face each and every day",
                    "To wake up beside you is a treasure that I have found in you and that I am thankful for.",
                    "Your beautiful eyes dance bright and clear and I can see forever in your eyes." };
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(sentences.length);

    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)    
    {
    ratemessage(sentences[rand]);  

    }       


    public static void ratemessage (String sentences) 

    {   
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( sentences ); 


        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what do you rate this sentence out of 10?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result = input.nextInt();
    }
        Arrays.sort(result);// this is the Array.sort()method

        for (int i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("you given rating is " + result + "for " + sentences);
        }
}
// END loopswithinloops
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the Random if want to randomize your sentences (you say 5 random sentences).
You don't need Scanner when you're using JOptionPane.

So this is how you could do it - I've added some comments:

```
String[] sentences = {"I am blessed to have you in my life. You are the one thing in my life that is true and real",
                        "I am honoured to have you by my side to love and to cherish each day of our lives.", 
                        "More precious than any other thing in my life is to see your face each and every day",
                        "To wake up beside you is a treasure that I have found in you and that I am thankful for.",
                        "Your beautiful eyes dance bright and clear and I can see forever in your eyes." };

int[] result = new int[sentences.length];//you have to give the array a size
String inputStr;
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sentences[i]);//the sentences one at at time 
    inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what do you rate this sentence out of 10?");
    result[i] = (int)Float.parseFloat(inputStr);//put the input into the array - it comes as a float so you'll have to cast it to int
} 
Arrays.sort(result);
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("you given rating is " + result[i] + " for " + sentences[i]);
}
```